# mysql 5.5 command line client error 1366 HY000 :incorrect string value:'\xD3\xE3\xC0

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJUJT.jpg)I want to insert many languages into my mysql database using command line client but the error still prompt out after i've try to change my collation of database, table into utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci. How to solve it?

I appreciate who can help this working.

Answer (score 0):

it is about one of the row in your database you should make sure your database or table is empty then do such things

Comment: so, is it to create new database and set the collation of database into utf8_general _ci then only can work as inserting many languages into mysql database?

Comment: no not create the database from the base
just clear the data and change the collation of database then insert the data again